# Alternatives to CoreLocation's requestLocation method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an IOS app where I require the user's current location in order to make an HTTP request to get data about nearby locations. Since I just need the user's location once, I am using the CoreLocation `requestLocation` method. This issue with this is that it takes roughly 10 seconds (which is stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation)). I realize that there will always be a delay which I am prepared for, but the delay on `requestLocation` is just too long and ruins the user experience.

I was wondering if anyone has thought of a way to get the users location (just once) in a more timely way.

One solution I thought of was perhaps calling the method within the AppDelegate, as the app starts, and then passing the data to the ViewControllers via some shared object. The issue I foresee here is that AppDelegate does complete it's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function very quickly so I don't think it'll improve my problem

Another solution I thought of could be to use the `startUpdatingLocation` method, and then use `stopUpdatingLocation` after receiving the first location. My issue with this is that `startUpdatingLocation` may also take a few seconds to start up ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation)), so again this may not improve my problem.

The location I get for the user does not need to be super accurate so I am willing to compromise on precision for performance.

Comment: It is not super fast but you can set the lowest desiredAccuracy (kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers ) possible to CLLocationManger. Definitely, it will improve performance little bits.

Comment: In my experience both requestLocation and startUpdatingLocation take 1 or 2 seconds, probably even less. Maybe the best you could do is to test it yourself and see if this can fit in the user experience you want to achieve.

Comment: Additionally your idea of using the AppDelegate might work. It doesn't matter if it completes quickly, you would need to set a delegate for CLLocationManager and this would be called asynchronously.